# PHP and mysql : mysql statements in php

Tags: php, mysql

I have a mysql query inside a php file which is selecting a bunch of names from a table and populating a drop down list. 
That's my first sql statement.

```
$sql1 = "SELECT DISTINCT AuthorLast FROM Author ORDER BY AuthorLast";
```

The issue is that one of the names is O'Kiefe.

My second sql statement is as follows, in which I run after pressing the submit button.

The issue is that since the name O'Kiefe contains an apostrophe, it's not running my second sql function the way I want.

```
$sql2 = "select distinct Book.Title from Book,Author,Wrote where Author.AuthorLast='$_POST[filter2]' and Author.AuthorNum=Wrote.AuthorNum and Wrote.BookCode=Book.BookCode";
```

Is there a way I can overcome this?...

Hope you can help.
Just learning php and mysql .
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use

```
mysql_real_escape_string()
```

**Warning
This extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0 , Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used.**

[REFERENCE](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php)

```
$author_last = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[filter2]);

$sql2 = "select distinct Book.Title from Book,Author,Wrote where Author.AuthorLast='$author_last' and Author.AuthorNum=Wrote.AuthorNum and Wrote.BookCode=Book.BookCode";
```

Comment: Thanks so much! it works just the way i wanted. appreciate that. I have a long way to go learning php! :)

Comment: Pleasure was all mine mate , just a quick suggestion try using PDO or MySqli . Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can use PDO (PHP Data Object) to interact with your Data Base, it handles the parametric query in itself and prevent from SQL Injection automatically.

Try this instead:

```
if($_POST["filter2"]){
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("select distinct Book.Title from Book,Author,Wrote where Author.AuthorLast='?' and Author.AuthorNum=Wrote.AuthorNum and Wrote.BookCode=Book.BookCode");
    $stmt->execute(array($_POST['filter2']));
 }
```

I recommend [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) (supported as of PHP 5.1)!